# Run-time error 1004 - Autofilter Method of Range Class Failed

Tags: excel, vba

When I run my vba, I get the

> Run-time error'1004; AutoFilter method of Range Class failed

I tried changing the worksheet as sheet 1 as it was recommended in a previous answer and it did not work

```
Sub Split_Data_in_workbooks()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim data_sh As Worksheet
Set data_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Working File")

Dim setting_Sh As Worksheet
Set setting_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setting")

Dim nwb As Workbook
Dim nsh As Worksheet

''''''Get unique districts


setting_Sh.Range("A:A").Clear
data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False
data_sh.Range("b:b").Copy setting_Sh.Range("A1")

setting_Sh.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes

Dim I As Integer

For I = 2 To Application.CountA(setting_Sh.Range("A:A"))

   data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 2, setting_Sh.Range("A" & I).Value

   Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
   Set nsh = nwb.Sheets(1)

   data_sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy nsh.Range("A1")

   nwb.SaveAs setting_Sh.Range("H6").Value & "/" & setting_Sh.Range("A" & 
I).Value & ".xlsx"
   nwb.Close False
   data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False
Next I

setting_Sh.Range("A:A").Clear

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

The code is supposed to take each district's information (which could be multiple lines), which from one workbook and save it into separate workbooks and save them in a designated file.  The code will not run pass this line

```
data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 2, setting_Sh.Range("A" & I).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably passing incorrect arguments to the `data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter` method. First argument must not be larger than the number of fields - try 1 instead of 2. Description of the second argument from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter):

> The criteria (a string; for example, "101"). Use "=" to find blank
>   fields, "<>" to find non-blank fields, and "><" to select (No Data)
>   fields in data types. If this argument is omitted, the criteria is
>   All. If Operator is xlTop10Items, Criteria1 specifies the number of
>   items (for example, "10").

Try this line and then play with different arguments' values. Make sure you know what argument values are you passing to the function:

```
data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 1
```

Comment: data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 1 - the number corresponds with the column that the data is sorted by.  When I change that number, I still get the same error.